# AngularJS : dynamic ng-model names in ng-repeat and display input fields sum

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-model

I have some simple data from which I'd like to create dynamic `ng-model` names from. I know that if you have those names handy you concatenate their input values together and display them, like so:

```
<p>{{blah--bleh}}</p>
```

But what if I don't know those ng-model names in advance, or how many there will be? How can I dynamically create those names and then for however many are created display the sum of their values that the user inputs?

If its not clear what I'm asking, [here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d5ug98ke/1/). I think you'll see what I'm going for.

The html

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <ul>
       <li ng-repeat="invoice in invoices">

            <input type="number" step="any" placeholder="Enter Amount" 
                    ng-model="invoice.salesOrder" />
       </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="sum"> Total Amount: ${{blah--blah}}
                </div><!-- READ ONLY -->

</div>
```

The js

```
var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', [])

.controller("MainCtrl", 
            function($scope) {

    $scope.invoices = [
        {
            "salesOrder": "5"       
        },
        {
            "salesOrder": "6"        
        },
        {
            "salesOrder": "7"  
        }
    ];


});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a function like so: http://jsfiddle.net/d5ug98ke/2/
This will calculate the total and update the bound variable anytime an input changes

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <ul>
       <li ng-repeat="invoice in invoices">               
            <input type="number" step="any" placeholder="Enter Amount" 
                    ng-model="invoice.salesOrder" ng-change="getSalesTotal()" />
       </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="sum"> Total Amount: ${{sum}}
                </div><!-- READ ONLY -->
</div>

var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', [])

.controller("MainCtrl", 
            function($scope) {
   $scope.sum = 0;
    $scope.invoices = [
        {
            "salesOrder": "5"       
        },
        {
            "salesOrder": "6"        
        },
        {
            "salesOrder": "7"  
        }
    ];

    $scope.getSalesTotal = function(){
        $scope.sum = 0;
        $scope.invoices.forEach(function(invoice){
            $scope.sum += parseInt(invoice.salesOrder, 10);
        });
    };   
});
```